# Filter results using $match in MongoDB aggregate returning blank array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodes

I have the following schema:

```js
const UserQualificationSchema = new Schema(
    {
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
        },
        qualification: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Qualification',
        },
        expiry_date: {
            type: Date
        }
    }
```

```js
const QualificationSchema = new Schema(
    {
        fleet: {
            type: [String], // Eg ["FleetA", "FleetB", "FleetC"]
            required: true,
        }
    }
```

I am searching the UserQualifications with filters in a table, to search them by fleet, qualification or expiry date.  I so far have the following aggregate:

```js
db.UserQualifications.aggregate([{
{
    $lookup: {
      from: 'qualifications',
      localField: 'qualification',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'qualification',
    },
},
{
  $unwind: '$qualification',
},
{
  $match: {
    $and: [
      'qualification.fleet': {
         $in: ["Fleet A", "Fleet C"],  // This works
       },
      expiry_date: {
         $lt: req.body.expiry_date,  // This works
       },
      qualification: { // Also tried 'qualification._id'
         $in: ["6033e4129070031c07fbbf29"] // Adding this returns blank array
      }
    ]
  },
}
}])
```

Filtering by fleet, and expiry date both work, independently and in combination, however when adding by the qualification ID, it returns blank despite the ID's being sent in being valid.

Am i missing something here?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your schema I can infer that qualification in `ObjectId` and in the query you are passing only the string value of `ObjectId`. You can pass the ObjectId to get your expected output

```
db.UserQualifications.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Qualifications",
      localField: "qualification",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "qualification",
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$qualification",
    
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "qualification.fleet": {
        $in: [
          "FleetA",
          "FleetC"
        ],
        
      },
      expiry_date: {
        $lt: 30 // some dummy value to make it work
      },
      "qualification._id": {
        $in: [
         // some dummy value to make it work
          ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000") 
        ]
      }
    },
    
  }
])
```

I have created a playground with some dummy data to test the query: [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZW-u5hUzI4a)

Also, In `$match` stage there is no need to combine query explicitly in `$and` as by default behaviour will be same as `$and` only so I have remove that part in my query

Comment: Adding to this answer If you get **ObjectId is not defined** you have to use `Mongoose.Types.ObjectId` after adding `const Mongoose = require('mongoose');`